# C# COMException reading property of MSWord Shape object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, .net, com, ms-word

I am trying to loop through all shapes in a document and check their "Alternate Text" which has had the source filename for that image recorded as it's alternate text. I need to read specific source images and convert them to a different image format.

I am able to get to the point of reading the AlternateText of the shape but it throws an exception: 
'((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape)(s)).AlternativeText' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

When I set a breakpoint and view the "s" object, the majority of properties are throwing this exception, however some are not, for example I can read the LinkFormat property and a few others without issue, but the majority of properties throw an error.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Word.Application WordApp = new Word.Application();
        d = WordApp.Documents.Open(@strFilename, ReadOnly: true, Visible: false);
        int iReplacements = 0;
        int iReplacementNoLink = 0;

        foreach (Word.Shape s in d.Shapes)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            try
            {
                if (s.LinkFormat.SourceName.ToString().Contains(".eps") || s.LinkFormat.SourceName.ToString().Contains(".png"))
                {
                    iReplacements++;
                }
                if (s.AlternativeText != "")
                {
                    iReplacementNoLink++;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception fff)
            {
                Console.Write(fff);
            }
        }
```

The if statement checking the s.AlternateText always ends up in the catch.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I have Office 2007, I am not sure if that is relevant or not.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to be able to read the Alternate Text of the shapes? If I am going about it in the wrong way or need to include a library or if I need to upgrade VS or Office? It seems like it should be really straight forward.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Hard to be sure without actually seeing a document, but in your place the first thing I'd do is open a document in Word, go to the VBA Editor (Alt+F11) and in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) query the property. Something like: ?ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).AlternativeText -- and then you press Enter. Either that will give you the text and you know it's a problem communicating from .NET with Word or an error message will pop-up - which may or may not give you better information about what the problem is.

Comment: Important note: A lot of different graphic objects fall into the category "Shape". Not all such objects support all properties available for a "Shape", so sometimes you have to determine what kind (type) of Shape you're dealing with before you can query it for certain properties. Are you CERTAIN the Shapes you're querying actually have AlternateText?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am positive that the shapes have "AlternativeText" I mis-typed it earlier as "AlternateText", but the code has/had the correct name. I can view the a"AlternativeText" in MSWord, by r-clicking the image, choosing "size" and then clicking the "AlternativeText" property. Also when viewing the object with watch, it lists the property, but it lists the comexception as it's value.

Comment: And the VBA trouble-shooting step I suggested? What's the result?

Comment: I made a procedure in VBA to iterate all the shapes and debug.print their alternative text and I am able to see the values I am looking for in the debug output. I used While i < ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
    Debug.Print (ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).AlternativeText)
    i = i + 1
Wend

Comment: A quick test here -  Word.Document doc = wdApp.ActiveDocument;  Word.Shape s = doc.Shapes[1]; System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(s.AlternativeText); - works with no issues. Also tried with an `if`. What is `Application.DoEvents` for in your code? If you comment that out? Does the other `if` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure why this worked, but I was able to resolve this issue by using the "Select" method of the shape. Once the shape is selected the majority of the properties that previously were throwing errors are populated. There are still approximately 20 properties that thow the error, but I am now able to access things like "AlternativeText","Name","Callout" which were previously throwing the error.

```
        Word.Application WordApp = new Word.Application();
        d = WordApp.Documents.Open(@strFilename, ReadOnly: true, Visible: false);
        int iReplacements = 0;
        int iReplacementNoLink = 0;
        foreach (Word.Shape s in d.Shapes)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            try
            {
                //if (s.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoLinkedPicture)
                if (s.LinkFormat.SourceName.ToString().Contains(".eps") || s.LinkFormat.SourceName.ToString().Contains(".png"))
                {
                    iReplacements++;
                }
                s.Select();
                if (s.AlternativeText != "" && s.AlternativeText != null)
                {
                    iReplacementNoLink++;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception fff)
            {
                Console.Write(fff);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I didn't have the exact same problem, but I had similar issues when looping through Document.Shapes.  Shape.Select() did the trick.  
I LOVE YOU MAN!!!!